# Consulta MySQL - Contar campos de tabelas distintas

Tags: mysql, query, count, sql-view

Estou precisando criar uma view no MySQL onde me retorne o seguinte resultado.

Col1 | Col2

Total Tab1 | Total Tab2

Estou utilizando UNION da forma abaixo, porém o resultado vem da seguinte forma:

**col1**

201

5699

```
CREATE VIEW `dashboards` AS (
  select 
    count(`clientes`.`id`) AS `col1` 
  from 
    `clientes`) union all (
  select 
    count(`titulos`.`id`) AS `col2` 
  from 
    `titulos`);
```

Mas preciso que retorne como colunas e não como linhas.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Costumo fazer assim:

```
select 
    count(clientes.id) as coluna1, count(titulos.id) as coluna2, sum(titulos.valor) as total
from
    clientes, titulos
```

Retorna algo assim:

```
coluna1 | coluna2 | total
  10    |    25   |   50
```

Se precisar de mais colunas com alguma fórmula chame no select adicionado vírgula para separar.

Comment: Perfeito, só faltou transformar em view, @Shura16.

Answer (score 1):

## Explicação

Você pode desenvolver sua query fazendo com que uma subquery seja um campo. Utilize como base o exemplo apresentado abaixo.

## Exemplo

```
  CREATE VIEW `dashboards` AS (
      SELECT (
      select 
        count(`clientes`.`id`) 
      from 
        `clientes`) AS `col1`,(
      select 
        count(`titulos`.`id`)  
      from 
        `titulos`) AS `col2`;
```